# Find in Files does not search through symbolic files

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
c:\temp\file.txt
c:\temp\symbolic.txt
```

If I have a workspace folder consisting of the two above files, the `symbolic.txt`  being a symbolic link file.

Any search in the **Find in Files** panel will only find results in the `file.txt` file. The `symbolic.txt` file is ignored.
If I have both of the files open in an editor and tick the option "Search only in open editors", then my searches are found in both files.

What is happening here? Does the "Find in Files" panel not support searching through symbolic files?

My paths are not case sensitive so, [THIS](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10633) does not apply.

I followed the suggested fix for [Follow symlinks doesn't work in search #99657](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99657), "Use Exclude settings and ignore files" button found in the "files to exclude" field is disabled, and the workspace is a simple test workspace with no ignore settings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit1:
As requested by starball

```
[Window Title]
Visual Studio Code

[Main Instruction]
Visual Studio Code

[Content]

Version: 1.85.1 (user setup)
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:49:37.021Z (1 mo ago)
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: @starball I have appended the requested information.Hmm if you're saying that it works for you then must be my code version? I will try to backup my Code settings and try it with a fresh installation. Thanks.